# Can't restart bind9 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, bind

When i want to configure mail server in my ubuntu, i have to restart bind9 after make a Domain Name Server (DNS), 
but it failed.

it says
rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused

What should I do?
Give me the solution.
I use linux ubuntu ver 12.04.

Comment: What does your config look like?  The config file may not be configured properly, causing this error.

Comment: Can you provide the log? You can run `named` with `-g` so the log is done to `stderr`.

Comment: Are you sure Bind is actually running?  Did you perhaps break your config so badly that it is refusing to start?  Look at your `/var/log/syslog` after trying to start/restart bind.